# Delete a specific filtered element

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

1. In the datand object
2. I want to access Creaalues and
   filter(startsWith('FL) && typeof el.value ===
   'object')
3. Once I retrieve the field, I remove the array newly created and I push the data to a new object createalues.
4. I then want to add creatalue to the dataToSend Object
5. And I delete the element filtered from the initial createalues array

```
//original object
const datend = {
  ID: 74,
  crealues: [{
      field: "F",
      value: 'hello',
    },
    {
      field: "F",
      fileName: "doc.pdf",
      value: {
        field: 'FL',
        fileName: 'bl.pdf',
        value: 'jkhkjhkhkjh'
      }
    }
  ]
}

// code in progress

const test = dataToSend.creatlues.filter(
        (el) => el.field.startsWith('FL') && typeof el.value === 'object'
    );
    datad.creatValues = test;



//output desired

const datnd = {
  createValues: [{
      field: "FLD_S",
      value: 'hello',
    }],
creatues: [{
      field: "FL1",
      value: 'hello',
    }
  ],
  creatlues:{
    field: 'FL2',
    fileName: 'bulletin_paie_avril.pdf',
    value: 'jkhkjhkhkjh'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use splice using index of the element you want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

You will need to use a loop;

```
const test = dataToSend.createValues.filter(
        (el) => el.field.startsWith('FLD_STR_') && typeof el.value === 'object'
    );
dataToSend.createFileValues = test;

test.foreach( ( obj ) => {
   dataToSend.createValues.splice( 0, 1, obj );
}
```

If you really for some reason don't want to use a loop and you know you will ever only want 1 item then you could do

```
const test = dataToSend.createValues.filter(
        (el) => el.field.startsWith('FLD_STR_') && typeof el.value === 'object'
    );
dataToSend.createFileValues = test;
dataToSend.createValues.splice( 0, 1, test[0] );
```

Comment: I updated my question. If you do not mind to have a look. thank you

Comment: I updated the answer, sorry I had 2 typos in it. let me know if this solves your question